# Should this question be reopened and/or edited?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I put this question, [Is smoking tobacco acceptable in any school of Buddhism?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/18732/254) on hold, because it may conflict two site policies:

1. One was the OP saying, "I will answer my own question" ... however posting questions in order to "preach" (i.e. because you want to give an answer, not because you want to receive an answer) is discouraged on this site
2. The other was the OP saying, "smoking is not a buddhist issue" ... which might make it off-topic.

If the OP only wants to ask the question (without the answer), then I guess that would be on-topic. I don't know.

I upvoted the question, only in order to give the OP [enough reputation to participate here on Meta](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reopened it after editing. The OP edited it to make it more on-topic.